# Высоконагруженное задание в cron

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Доброго времени суток. Стоит задача реализовать на сайте функцию, которая раз в сутки будет делать необходимую проверку на сайте. Проблема в том что такая проверка занимает большое кол-во времени, так как для ее реализации необходимо выполнять обращение к другим ресурсам и работать (по приблизительным подсчетам) с 100 тыс. записей из базы данных.

Язык php. Фреймворк Yii2. База данных MySQL

Суть вопроса в следующем, какие есть практики для подобных проблем, когда не хватает времени на выполнения скрипта и он заканчивает свою работу? По поим подсчетам на полное выполнение скрипта уйдет около 2х часов. Как лучше это реализовывать?

Заранее благодарен за советы и ответы!

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

В базу данных добавляете индексное поле, например, `tested` типа `int(1)` со значением по умолчанию `0`. Когда скрипт проверил запись, он ставит ему значение `1`. Поскольку индекс короткий, это не вызовет замедление записи в базу. Запускайте скрипт не раз в сутки, а раз в 10 минут, пусть он лочит себя функцией `flock` для предотвращения повторного запуска, выбирает 100 непроверенных записей и обрабатывает их. Не успел - не беда, при следующем запуске обработает. По поводу обращения к другим ресурсам - здесь время выполнения этого под Linux не считается, под Windows считается, по крайней мере для SAPI модуля Apache. Вот как под CLI, не уверен.

По поводу запуска раз в сутки, если скрипт будет создавать высокую нагрузку на протяжении значительного времени, за это хостер может и по попе надавать, если у вас не VDS.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, это не на 100% подходит мне, но за то благодаря Вам понял как это адаптировать под мои реалии и выполнить задачу свою.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте работу с очередями, например `yiisoft/yii2-queue` может помочь в реализации этой задачи.

Comment: пожалуйста, распишите вашу мысль чуть более подробнее, приведите пример

Comment: Попытайтесь писать более развернутые ответы